# If $f(x+\Delta x) = f(x) + g(\Delta x)$, then is $f$ a linear function?

Tags: functions

I edited the whole question, even the title. Originally, I wanted to know if non-linear functions could have the following property: Same amount of change in $x$ always corresponds to a constant change in $f(x)$.

From Cauchy's functional equations, under regularity conditions, it follows that if $f(x+\Delta x) = f(x) + f(\Delta x)$, then $f$ is a linear function. But it doesn't answer my question completely, since $f(\Delta x)$ is a certain type of constant.

Comment: Your title and the body of your question are different: in the title you have "$c$ subscript $\Delta x$" whereas in your question you have "$m$ times $\Delta x$".

Comment: @LeeMosher Kindly take a look at the edit, please.

Comment: That clarifies several confusions, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that this is meant to be a function from real numbers to real numbers.

It follows by induction from what you write that

$$g(n\Delta x)=mn\Delta x+c$$

for all integers $n$, where $c=g(0)$. If the property is meant to hold for all possible real number shifts $\Delta x$*, then we can choose $\Delta x=1/l$ for an integer $l$ to get

$$g(n/l)=m(n/l)+c$$

So, for rational inputs ($x$ is rational if it is the ratio of two integers), the only possible functions with this property are in the form $g(x)=mx+c$.

You may be interested in reading

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation

Your equation is an example of a functional equation, related to the one in the article.

*If the condition holds for a particular value of $\Delta x$ only, then there are clearly more solutions. Namely, if we add to $g$ any periodic function with period $\Delta x$.

*To answer the new, edited question, if $f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)=g(\Delta x)$ for all $x,\Delta x$ then, for rationals $x$, $f(x)=mx+c$ for some real $m,c$ and $g(x)=mx$ for the same $m$. Again, there are solutions which don't take this form. To describe them, we would use a $\mathbb{Q}$-basis for $\mathbb{R}$, i.e. a set $B$ of real numbers such that any real number may be written uniquely as a finite sum $\sum a_ib_i$ with $b_i\in B$ and $a_i\in \mathbb{Q}$. Given such a set we define $f(\sum a_ib_i)=\sum a_im_i+c_i$ for reals $m_i,c_i$ and $g(\sum a_ib_i)=\sum a_im_i$.

Comment: Sorry, if I'm being too dumb. But I don't understand why you would work with the function $g$, and not with $f$.

Comment: I couldn’t understand the proof, but I read the Wikipedia article. Cauchy's additive functional equation seems to be the key. I have one confusion though. $f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)=f(\Delta x)$, where $f(\Delta x)$ is a constant depending on $\Delta x$. But what if the right hand side were $h(\Delta x)$? Would $f$ still be a linear function?

Comment: The use of $g$ rather than $f$ doesn't indicate anything, I can't remember why I chose it.

Comment: Suppose $f(x+3)-f(x)=30$ and $f(x+2)-f(x)=40$, since $g(3) = 30$ and $g(2) = 40$. It proves $f$ can't be a linear function since, for linear functions, a smaller change in $x$ can't produce a bigger change in $y$ compared to a bigger change in $x$. Right?

Comment: In this case we would have $f(x+6)-f(x)=f(x+6)-f(x+3)+f(x+3)-f(x)=2\cdot 30=60$ on the one hand, but also $f(x+6)-f(x)=f(x+6)-f(x+4)+f(x+4)-f(x+2)+f(x+2)-f(x)=3\cdot 40=120$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: As said in my answer, for rational $x$, the only solutions are $f(x)=mx+c$ and $g(x)=mx$.

Comment: I couldn't understand the answer completely but I think I got it reading your comment. I am up-voting it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Note that your function is not quite linear but affine. since $g(x+y)$ is not equal to $g(x)+g(y)$. But I know what you mean.

So suppose there exists a function $g$ such that $g(x+h)-g(x)=mh$ for all $h$ and $x$.

then dividing by $h$ and taking the limit as $h$ tends to $0$ we see:

$$g'(x)=m$$

Integrating the above equation we get $g(x)=mx+a$ for some constant $a$.

Edit:

To show rigorously that the limit exists, note that

$\dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} - m = \dfrac{mh}{h} - m = 0$

For all $h$, hence the limit tends to zero. As you can see, this was quite trivial to show.

Comment: You need to show that this limit exists

Comment: This is trivial: Just hypothesize that the derivative is $m$ and show that the limit of $(f(x+h)-f(x)-mh)/h$ tends to zero.

Comment: @Leonid So, this proves that only linear functions have this property. Right?

Comment: Only linear (up to a constant) functions, yes.

Comment: Also, whoever downvoted me is free to explain themselves. But I hope it's not because of the need to show differentiability of $g$, since this is trivial; I didn't think it needed to be explained, but I'll edit the post if necessary.

Comment: Why did you suppose $g(x+h)-g(x)=mh$ and then show that $g(x) = mx + c$? I think it doesn't prove: If $f(x+ \Delta x) - f(x) = c_{\Delta x}$ for all $\Delta x$ where $c_{\Delta x}$ is a constant depending on $\Delta x$, $f$ is necessarily a linear function.

Comment: That was my assumption since your question was asking if there is a nonlinear function $f$ satisfying the property $f(x+h)-f(x)=ch$ unless you meant to write $c(h)$? i.e. $c$ is a function depending on $h$ as opposed to being multiplied by $h$?

Comment: If delta doesn't go to 0, were a finite Taylor expansion making sense ?

Comment: @Leonid, exactly that. I didn't mean $c\Delta x$. I meant $f(x+ \Delta x) - f(x) = c$ where $c$ is a constant and depends on $\Delta x$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $f(x+\Delta x)=f(x)+g(\Delta x)$.

If $0$ is in the domain of $f$ then $f(0+\Delta x)=f(0)+g(\Delta x)$.

Thus $f(\Delta x)=f(0)+g(\Delta x)$ for $\Delta x$ in the domain of $f$.

In other words.

$$ g(x)=f(x)-f(0) $$

This places constraints on the function $f$. For example, there is no such function $g$ for a quadratic function, as is easily demonstrated. However, as others have pointed out, such a function $g$ exists for affine functions.

If $f(x)=ax+b$, then $g(x)=f(x)-f(0)=ax$.

So $f(x+\Delta x)=a(x+\Delta)x+b=ax+b+a\Delta x=f(x)+g(\Delta x)$

Unless $b=0$, $f(x)=ax+b$ is not linear since $f(x+\Delta x)\ne f(x)+f(\Delta x)$.

Comment: "This places constraints on the function $f$. For example, there is no such function $g$ for a quadratic function...," could you explain how the preceding equation places constraints on $f$? And what is the constraint exactly? And you assumed $0$ is in the domain of $f$. What if it isn’t? And can $f$ be any other function other than linear?

Comment: @MostafizurRahman I meant that the condition $g(x)=f(x)-f(0)$ is a necessary but not sufficient condition for $g$ to have the desired property. The issue is this: "What kind of function $f$ can have a corresponding function $g$ such that for $x$ and $x+\Delta x$ in the domain of $f$ it is the case that $f(x+\Delta x) =f(x)+g(\Delta x)$. OP wants to know if only linear functions have this property. This is answered in the negative since affine functions have that property. One could also ask whether *only* affine functions have such a propery, but that is a different question.

Comment: I think I should've said affine functions in the question instead of linear functions. Does *only* affine functions have this property? Am I asking too much?